# Как поставить задержку на наведение JQuery?

Tags: javascript, jquery

Делаю выпадающие меню. Пробовал уже добавлять setTimeout, но он вообще перестает работать.
Как тут поставить задержку?

```
$('.nav .dropdown').on({
   mouseenter: function () {
   $(this).addClass('open');
  },
   mouseleave: function () {
   $(this).removeClass('open');
  }
});
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Решил вопрос xD
Спасибо)

```
var timer, pause = 400;
$(".nav").on("mouseenter mouseleave", ".dropdown", function(event) {
  window.clearTimeout(timer);
  var that = this;
  if (event.type == "mouseenter") {
    timer = window.setTimeout(function() {
       that.classList.add("open")
    }, pause)
  } else this.classList.remove("open")
});
```